# How to pass .yaml file as argument in pytest command line

Tags: arguments, pytest, app.yaml, parametrize

I have multiple .yaml files each containing shell or python commands and I want to execute them separately based on the need through command line arguments in pytest execution .

test_code.yaml

```
**.yaml file content :**

test_execute_impala_query:
- change_dir_path: /home/a/
  sql_result: ksh -x /home/impala_query.sh /sandbox/home/impala_export_query.sql  /sandbox/home/actual_result.csv output_delimiter=,

test_file_compare:
 - file_compare_check: python3 /sandbox/pytest_execution/test_compare_file.py  --file1 /sandbox/venv/smoke_test/actual_result_prsn.csv --file2 /sandbox/smoke_test/expected_result.csv
```

Actual Pytest script

test_code_check.py

```
import pytest
import os
import parametrize_from_file
import pandas as pd
import subprocess
import sys


@parametrize_from_file
def test_execute_impala_query(change_dir_path,sql_result):
    os.chdir(change_dir_path)
    result = subprocess.run([sql_result],shell=True,check=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    assert result.returncode == 0



@parametrize_from_file
def test_file_compare(file_compare_check):
    result = subprocess.run([file_compare_check],shell=True,check=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    assert result.returncode == 0
```

Here, the above code perfectly works fine but that .yaml filename I need to pass it through command line

I have to execute the below way to get the output

```
pytest test_code_check.py --test_file test_code.yaml  

pytest test_code_check.py --test_file test_code_2.yaml
```